# How can the probability of two disjoint events be non-zero?

Tags: probability, statistical-ai

Let $A$ and $B$ be two models for a classification task. Let $x$ be a test set and $M$ be a metric for the classification task.  $X$ be a random variable on test sets.

Now,

$M(A,x) = $ Score of model $A$ on test set $x$

$M(B,x)$ = Score of model $B$ on test set $x$

$\delta(x) =$ difference in performance of models wrt test set $x$  $= M(A, x)-M(B,x)$

Now, consider the following (statistical) hypothesis on the performance difference $\delta$

$$H_o : \delta(x)  \le 0$$
$$H_1 : \delta(x)  > 0$$

We define $p-$value as follows

$$P(\delta(X) \ge \delta(x) | H_o  \text{is true} ) $$

With this as context, I confused with the following paragraph (taken from p15 of [Naive Bayes and Sentiment Classification](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ejurafsky/slp3/4.pdf))

> So in our example, this $p-$value is the probability that we would see
> $\delta(x)$ assuming $A$ is not better than B. If $\delta(x)$ is huge
> (let’s say $A$ has a very respectable $M$ of $.9$ and $B$ has a
> terrible $M$ of only $.2$ on $x$), we might be surprised, since that
> would be extremely unlikely to occur if $H_0$ were in fact true, and so
> the **$p-$value would be low** (unlikely to have such a large $\delta$ if
> $A$ is in fact not better than $B$). But if $\delta(x)$ is very small,
> it might be less surprising to us even if $H_0$ were true and $A$ is
> not really better than $B$, and so the $p-$value would be higher.

It is told in the paragraph that $p-$value is very low if $A's$ performance is better than $B$.

I am thinking that $p-$value should be zero if $A's$ performance is better than $B$ since it is a disjoint event wrt $H_0$. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I don't have a definitive answer and I am also not a statistician, but from my understanding of statistical tests, the p-value is a **probability** of your _test statistic_, which can, for example, be the t-statistic (for the t-test). Therefore, the p-value **depends on** the probability distribution of the associated test statistic, which depends on your **assumptions** about our data (the t-statistic is computed as a function of your data). I think to fully answer this question it's required to understand what the test statistic and the associated prob. distribution are here.

Comment: This is the type of question to which you should find more qualified people to answer on Cross Validated SE, as this is really a question about a statistics topic, although statistical tests are also used in AI and research areas that use or apply AI. I think we can consider this question on-topic here, as it's in the context of Naive Bayes and NLP, but it's something that we may want to discuss on meta.